# Why does text is not coming exactly to center even thought tried changing with Height & Width in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Please see this expected image below, in screenshot it is looking big but I want to make it very small, for that you can see my textview dimensions..[image]

This is my output after spending whole day on this, **but the problem is + is not coming into center**: [image]

Now this is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        style="@style/match_match"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_16"
        android:background="@drawable/product_list_cardview_border"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_2">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_16">
...
...
  <com.test.consumer.utils.CustomTextViewV2
                android:id="@+id/tv_item_plus"
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_10"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_style_item_default"
                android:text="+"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                android:textSize="9sp"
                app:customFont="@string/font_raleway_semibold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_final_mrp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Please note: I don't want to take any other nested view, the ideal solution fix should be: Textview should be inside parent constraint layout.

Background drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/dimen_1"
        android:color="@color/color_moderate_gray_shade_one" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

Also, I tried with imageview as well!

Answer (score 0):

//Take relative layout as parent and inside that layout put image view.(Copy and
paste this)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/circle">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_circle_outline_24" />

            </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it works for you?

Comment: This solutuion is not ideal, because I don't want to use nested layout, textview or imageview should be directly inside constraint layout

Answer (score 0):

Using ShapeableImageView, we can give strokeWidth & strokeColor.

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:id="@+id/siv_plus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    android:padding="2dp"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedImageViewStyle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:strokeColor="@color/black"
    app:strokeWidth="1dp" />
```

Add following lines in your themes.xml/style.xml

```
 <style name="RoundedImageViewStyle" parent="Theme.MyApplication">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">12dp</item>
</style>
```

Replace 'Theme.MyApplication' with your parent theme name.

[See Output (screenshot.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4g2N.png)

Comment: This solution won't work because border color should be different and border width also should be different

Comment: You can update border color as per you want, maybe like app:strokeColor="@color/red" or any custom in your colors.xml, same for its width